# Do you know how to resolve the "Couldn't authenticate" problem on ZendeskAPI?

Tags: python, api, zendesk, zendesk-api

I'm trying to connect my zendeskAPI to create a ticket with a python application but I surely missed something because I just got the "Couldn't authenticate you" error, I've created and activate the api token in Zendesk and I tried in Postman But i came to the same error.

Here its my url and the headers (the variables are correctly connected)
[image]

And the token authorization added too

[image]

I already saw some topics with the same problem but no solutions worked. Do you have an idea ?

I tried to use Webhooks on Zendesk but the company i work for doesn't have the extension. Is it possible to install it ?

Comment: put the / at the end of the tickets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For postman authorization, you need to set the type to *Basic Auth* rather than *API Key*. It will encode your username *{{mail}}/token* and API token for you. You will **NOT** need to manually add an authorization header and encode the credentials separately.

Also if you are using python, consider using a [community developed client](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/api-clients/python/) that would make your API calls much easier. **Zenpy** is still maintained.